# Firebase: Update Firestore Fails If Document Does Not Exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

With Firestore, the below fails and gives me a gnarly error if I'm writing a new user(uid). It works if I use `.set` for a non-existent document. Firebase Realtime DB allows me to use `.update` to create a new record.

My question is: is this expected behavior for Firestore or is my script bad?

```
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
    var thisUid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(thisUid);
    var o = {};
    docRef.get().then(function(thisDoc) {
        if (thisDoc.exists) {
            //user is already there, write only last login
            o.lastLoginDate = Date.now();
            docRef.update(o);
        } else {
            //new user
            o.displayName = firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName;
            o.accountCreatedDate = Date.now();
            o.lastLoginDate = Date.now();
            // Send it
            docRef.update(o);
        }
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
    toast(error.message);
});
```

The error I get is:

```
error.js:149 Uncaught (in promise) Error: no entity to update: app: "s~myapp-abcdefg"<br/>path <<br/>  Element {<br/>    type: "users"<br/>    name: "WlM8mo-my-long-uid-h4pu2"<br/>  }<br/>><br/>
    at new e (error.js:149)
    at webchannel_connection.js:241
    at X.<anonymous> (webchannel_connection.js:185)
    at Cb (index.js:22)
    at X.g.dispatchEvent (index.js:20)
    at Ce.Ea (index.js:94)
    at ke.g.Na (index.js:82)
    at Tc (index.js:43)
    at Sc (index.js:40)
    at L.g.Ra (index.js:38)
```

Comment: Your first statement, exists, checks if there is any data. If there is any data, you can use update. With your else statement, you know that there is not any data. Any update will fail. Use set in your else statement.

Comment: `update` works in firebase for creating new records and not in firestore. Feature parity would be great. The problem w `set` is that it erased all properties not explicitly handed to it, and basically, in firebase rt-db, there is a zero use case scenario for it. So, I figured out the problem myself and posted it, including the gnarly error, to save others time. HTH